# How to escape an iframe and go to a separate website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, window, refresh

On one of my website's pages, call it http://website1.com/path, I have an iframe whose source is one of my other websites.

example: `<iframe src="http://website2.com"></iframe>`

I have a button on website2.com that drives them to the home page of website1.com.

However, when they click that button, website1.com just loads in the iframe. How do I get it to refresh the page and drive them to website1.com as it's own page?

I tried window.top.location.reload() and it didn't work..

Comment: hello, are you using jsp or normal html ?

Comment: im using html (php in particular)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's a link:

```
<a href="blah" target="_top">Click me!</a>
```

You can also do `target="_parent"`, which is useful if you have nested frames and only want to go up one level.

(On that subject, if you want to specifically go up TWO levels... you can't. At least not in HTML. JavaScript: `parent.parent.location.href = "xyz";`)